# Can you become a Ranger?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

In Fallout: New Vegas, you meet many ranger NPCs, among which is Ranger Andy in Novac who seems to suggest that it's possible for the Courier to become one. I came to the conclusion of a possibility from a question the Courier asks Andy:

> How does one become a Ranger?

to which Andy replies something along the lines of

> Yew need to be the meanest, toughest, takenocrapiest sonuvabitch this side of the Jawjuh, hoo-wee!

(approximate quote)

Is there a way to become a Ranger, or am I just interpreting the dialogue wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, you cannot become a Ranger. They're a specific type or rank of faction soldier (with the NCR in this case),

> and you can't actually *join* any faction to be given an official rank with them.

However, it *is* possible to get hold of the NCR Ranger [combat armor](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/New_California_Ranger_armor) or [patrol armor](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/NCR_Ranger_patrol_armor) and dress as one, but there's no specific bonuses for doing so (and the usual results associated with wearing faction armour). And don't forget the signature pistol: the [Ranger Sequoia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ranger_Sequoia).

Comment: Aww, that sucks. I had the theme to Walker: Texas Ranger all memorized and stuff. :(

Comment: The armor isn't even that good.

Comment: Looks pretty awesome, though... Although, I didn't even care about the armor that much, I just wanted to be Ranger Ragnar :P